# Opening a PHP project in eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse

I know in Visual Studio, for exemple, to open a C# project, we have to open the solution.  I a PHP project and Eclipse PHP to open it.  How to I proceed to open the PHP project? Cause unlike C#, I do not have a solution here.  Do u import the PHP project in eclipse and set the root directory where the project is?  Is this the correct way of doing it?

Comment: does the way you suggest work?

Comment: @DevDonkey : no, it does not.  I get the error : "No projects are found to import".

Answer (score -1):

If by "project" you mean actual Eclipse project, i.e. directory containing Eclipse `.project` file:

`File -> Import -> Existing Projects into Workspace -> Select root directory`

If by "project" you mean a bunch of existing PHP sources you'd like to create a new Eclipse project from:

```
File -> New PHP Project -> Create project at existing location (from existing source)
```

Comment: I believe it is an Eclipse project.  However, I get the "No projects are found to import" error.

Comment: Have you verified there is in fact a `.project` file in the directory you're selecting?

Comment: Yes, I have verified and there are none. Do you have any idea of how to proceed?

Comment: I have just noticed that in the import first window, we have a PHP option which opens a Phar file.  Could it be that one?

Comment: above method is not working kindly can any one update this post for correct method.

Answer (score -1):

I was facing the same issue, I was tring to import WordPress project into my eclipse.

**using Oxygen, with PHP (PDT) plugin installed**.

I resolved it by

```
New --> Project -->php Project
```

Create PHP Project wizard will be open.

```
Select create project with existing location (from existing source) 

And also provide the project name.
```

Then only the finish button will be come active.
click on finish button you project will be imported as PHP project.

Comment: your above method is also  not working kindly update for correct method. I am using Eclipse Oxygen

Comment: Is your PHP (PDT) plugin installed?

Comment: yep i have installed the eclipse pdt plugin

Comment: You can see this Image @RishiKeshPathak   [PDT IMAGE LINK](https://ibb.co/gabztT)